# How to flash ROM from app?

Tags: android, flash, recovery, rom

I am trying to make updater for custom rom. 
I can get to recovery from my app by:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
os.write("mkdir -p /cache/recovery/\n".getBytes());
os.write("echo 'boot-recovery' >/cache/recovery/command\n".getBytes());
os.write("reboot recovery\n".getBytes());
os.flush();
```

If I add next lines, device will load to recovery, clear cache and boot to system.

```
os.write("echo '--whipe-cache' >>/cache/recovery/command\n".getBytes());
os.write("echo 'reboot' >> /cache/recovery/command\n".getBytes());
```

Is there command to execute flashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this line:

```
os.write("echo '--update_package=/sdcard/update.zip' >>/cache/recovery/command\n".getBytes());
```

before

```
 os.write("reboot recovery\n".getBytes());
 os.flush();
```

Comment: if I add `os.write("echo '--whipe-cache' >>/cache/recovery/command\n".getBytes());` before `reboot-recovery` cache will be cleared, maybe there is simillar command for flashing?

Comment: Try this: '--update_package=/sdcard/update.zip' and let me know, if it works i will edit my answer!

Comment: That works, add that comment as an answer. Can you post link to list of those commands?